# trigger more or equal two, reacts only on more than two

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS owners (
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(30),
  last_name VARCHAR(30),
  address VARCHAR(255),
  city VARCHAR(80),
  telephone VARCHAR(20),
  INDEX(last_name)
) engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pets (
  id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  birth_date DATE,
  type_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  owner_id INT(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  INDEX(name),
  FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owners(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES types(id)
) engine=InnoDB;




create trigger petadd_trigger4 before insert on pets
     for each row
         begin
         DECLARE pets_amount int;

         SELECT COUNT(*) INTO pets_amount FROM pets p WHERE p.owner_id=new.owner_id;



         if (pets_amount>=2)
         then 
         signal sqlstate '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Too many pets';          

         end if;
```

I don't understand why this trigger reacts only when I add more than two animals. It's some kind of bug? Because it should reacts when I tried to add second animal

Comment: I advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I don't think your trigger is doing what you think it is.  `FOR EACH ROW` means that the logic executes once, for _each_ row, not in aggregate.

Comment: This sort of thing may also be hard to enforce.  For example, if there is room for only one more pet, what happens?  Do you block an insert of two records, or do you allow one insert only to proceed?

Comment: What @TimBiegeleisen says is true i don't believe that there is a (easy) way to limit records per group in MySQL when inserting or updating.. Why not the other way around? select the "TOP 2" pets from every user..

Comment: Not related to your question. But you probably want to said "Too many pets"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before inserting a new record your trigger counts the already inserted records for the owner. If there are already 2 then it will not allow to insert another one.

I think you are looking for

```
if (pets_amount > 0)
```